# The most effective way to import large csv files into Cassandra

Tags: csv, import, cassandra

I have 12 CSV files (~36 GB in total), which I need to load into Cassandra. Currently I'm running a job to parse the CSV files into an object and then run a row by row insert execution on Cassandra and it's taking forever (xx hours - which might be reality as well), but perhaps someone know a far more effective way?

Thank you for the sparring.

Comment: why not import via `cqlsh` itself?

Comment: @AlexOtt mainly due to cleaning data, the dataset is fluctuating a little bit in type, so my data isn't clean-clean, hence I was looking for effective ways to either batch it into cass or something like it. But in general you're right, I could use cqlsh as an option. I don't have better reason. :)

Comment: If you have Spark, then it can effectively parallelize loading. If you don't have it, then you can use async operations with your code in any language

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cassandra BulkLoader. The details of how to execute the load is clearly explained here https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated

Comment: Looks promissing, I'll have a look to it. I also found this article that cast some ideas off, at least in terms of write methods. 
https://dzone.com/articles/efficient-cassandra-write